# Shared Photo doesn't work in iOS 8.1 and 8.3 on device. Works in Simulator for 8.1

Tags: ios, xamarin, share

I am using a simulator that is iOS 8.1, it works, but in iOS 8.3 doesnt work.

And for real iphone, I tested with iOS 8.1.2 and 8.3, doesnt work both.

when I choose my app to share, this screen doesn't appear  (this simulator is iOS 8.1)

[image]

What could be problem?

I am using Xamarin iOS. Installed the last version of all.

Edit:
 info.plist

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>en</string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>ShareExtension</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>ShareExtension</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>aa.xx.cc.iOSShareExtension</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>aa.xx.cc.iOSShareExtension</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>XPC!</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1</string>
    <key>NSExtension</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExtensionAttributes</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExtensionPointName</key>
            <string>com.apple.share-services</string>
            <key>NSExtensionPointVersion</key>
            <string>1.0</string>
            <key>NSExtensionActivationRule</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsFileWithMaxCount</key>
                <integer>0</integer>
                <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsImageWithMaxCount</key>
                <integer>1</integer>
                <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsMovieWithMaxCount</key>
                <integer>0</integer>
                <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsText</key>
                <false/>
                <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsWebURLWithMaxCount</key>
                <integer>1</integer>
                <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsWebPageWithMaxCount</key>
                <integer>1</integer>

            </dict>
        </dict>
        <key>NSExtensionMainStoryboard</key>
        <string>MainInterface</string>
        <key>NSExtensionPointIdentifier</key>
        <string>com.apple.share-services</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: Maybe you have some code?

Comment: @Azat, This is not about the code.. I added some keys and values in plist for my extension project. I edited the post